# How to display jquery msgBox after data is inserted to MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, msgbox

I want to show a message box when data is already inserted in to MySQl table. My code is as below :

```
 if($insert_query)
    {  
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    $.msgBox('Data Added');
    window.location = 'bentry.php'; 
    </script> 
    }
```

But alert is not shown. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Correct your code first. The code you regarded above should generate PHP error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $.msgBox('Data Added');
    window.location = 'bentry.php'; 
    </script> "
```

OR

```
if($insert_query)
    {  ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
    $.msgBox('Data Added');
    window.location = 'bentry.php'; 
    </script> 
  <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Your second option is my original code , which is not working.. Problem is the demo example given in Jquery.msBOx it shows the msgbox when someone clicked but I want it to be shown when some condition is true.

Comment: @JayantaKumarNath 1. No..You dont have closing/opening braces. That makes it diffrent. 2.Is the condition being true? Do a normal alert instead of msg box to check if the solution is working. If it works, then you have a probelm with msgbox library.

Comment: when i use alert("Data Added"); its working but when tried to replace that with msgbox it does not work. So for the time being I put alert . But want to know what is the problem.

Comment: @JayantaKumarNath Exactly what i thought. Have you included all libraries required for msgbox? Are you calling the function correctly?

Comment: Yes I included all the libraries that neede... but I am sure that calling of the function is creating problem.... as when I added data .. the data got inserted into the table but no alert msgbox shows..

Answer (score 0):

the reason is

```
 window.location = 'bentry.php';
```

`$.msgBox('Data Added');` is loaded but redirection script naviagted into another page.

Comment: Even if i remove window.location = 'bentry.php'; its not showing the msgbox

Comment: Did you check msgbox related libraries included in your page

Comment: which library you have used, what is the name of your libraray

Comment: libraries that I include are

<script type="text/javascript" src="msgbox/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="msgbox/css/jquery.msgbox.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="msgbox/js/jquery.msgbox.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you try this, `<script type='text/javascript'>  $(function(){   $.msgBox('Data Added');}); </script>`

Comment: Can you provide fiddle demo along with your msgbox librabries

Answer (score -1):

```
if($insert_query)
{  
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$.msgBox('Data Added');
setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'bentry.php';},1000); 
</script> 
}
```